# Get time numbers inside div with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, time, woocommerce

Im building e-commerce website on wordpress and I want to style woocommerce preorder countdown.
Countdown is created with jQuery Countdown by Keith Wood. What I need is to style only numbers: *change their size and background*. Im not familiar with Jquery and i dont know how to split text or something like this. Also, I dont know is that really possible.

```
<div class="woocommerce-pre-orders-countdown hasCountdown" id="woocommerce-pre-orders-countdown-1592892000">  6 Days 22 Hours 58 Minutes 12 Seconds</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var txt = $('.hasCountdown').text();
var splited = txt.split('');
var flag = true;
var man = '';
var st = '';
for (var i = 0; i < splited.length; i++) {
  if ((48 >= splited[i].charCodeAt(0)) || (splited[i].charCodeAt(0) <= 57)) {
    st += splited[i];
    flag = false;
  } else {
    flag = true;
  }
  if (flag && st) {
    man += '&nbsp<span style="font-size:40px;background:red">' + st + '</span>&nbsp' + splited[i];
    st = '';
  } else {
    if (flag && !st) {
      man += splited[i];
    }
  }
}
$('.hasCountdown').html(man);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="woocommerce-pre-orders-countdown hasCountdown" id="woocommerce-pre-orders-countdown-1592892000"> 6 Days 22 Hours 58 Minutes 12 Seconds</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vanilla-flavored solution that grabs the contents of the div, **wraps each number is a styled span element**, and overwrites the div contents with the new version.

You can **choose your preferred size and color** by changing the values of `sizeMultiplier` and `background` variables. It'd be cleaner to use a CSS class to provide the formatting (and the script would just apply the CSS class) but I didn't know how easy it would be for you to modify the CSS files.

See the in-code comments for some further explanation.

```js
let
  // Options -- these determine the number formatting
  sizeMultiplier = 1.5,
  background = "lightskyblue";

const
  // Identifies HTML elements
  element = document.getElementById("my-div"),
  tempDiv = document.createElement("div"),
  btn = document.querySelector('button');

// Makes button work for demo
btn.addEventListener('click', formatNums);

// Replaces HTML in element with formatted version
function formatNums(){
  // Makes array from div contents, then converts item to DOM nodes
  const tokens = element.textContent.split(" ");
  const nodes = tokens.map( (token) =>
    // Numbers get formatted, other text is left as-is
    isNum(token)
      ? numSpan(token, sizeMultiplier, background)
      : textNode(token)
  );
  // Puts all the nodes into an empty div
  nodes.forEach( (node, i) => {
    tempDiv.appendChild(node);
    tempDiv.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
      i < nodes.length - 1 ? " " : ""
    );
  });
  // Replaces contents of original element
  element.innerHTML = tempDiv.innerHTML;
}

// Tests whether each item is a number
function isNum(token){
  return parseFloat(token) < Infinity
}

// Makes basic nodes for regular text
function textNode(word){
  return document.createTextNode(word);
}
// Makes a styled span for a number
function numSpan(num, size, color){
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  span.style.fontSize = size +"em";
  span.style.padding = size/4 + "ch"; // Makes background wider than num
  span.style.backgroundColor = color;
  span.textContent = num;
  return span;
}
```

```css
button{ margin: 10px; border-radius: 0.3em; }
```

```html
<button>APPLY FORMATTING</button>
<div id="my-div"> 6 Days 22 Hours 58 Minutes 12 Seconds</div>
```